# Error in SQL Server updating Image datatype from a linked server

Tags: sql-server

This is a table in a Microft Dynamics 2009 database.  Our Test database is missing a bunch of Image data, so I would like to update the table in test with the data in production.  I'm using this SQL for this update.  When I execute this, I get this error:

> Msg 8180, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Statement(s) could not be prepared.
>   Msg 306, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
>   The text, ntext, and image data types cannot be compared or sorted, except when using IS NULL or LIKE operator.

Query:

```
UPDATE INVENTTABLE 
SET
    Z_IMAGE = i2.Z_IMAGE,
    Z_IMAGEMIMETYPE = i2.Z_IMAGEMIMETYPE
FROM INVENTTABLE i1
    JOIN [PRODSQLSERVER].[DAX2009DB].[dbo].INVENTTABLE i2
        ON i1.RECID = i2.RECID
WHERE i2.Z_IMAGE IS NOT NULL
```

I can't see a place where I'm attempting to compare or sort the Image data.

Comment: The only thing I can think of is maybe try swapping the is not null for (CASE WHEN i2.Z_IMAGE IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) = 1 and see if it likes that.

Comment: I didn't even have the WHERE clause at first, and still go the error, so I don't think the Error is related.  I don't care if all the records get updated, so the where was a simple attempt at a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing UPDATE INVENTTABLE to UPDATE i1.

Comment: i2 is the alias for the Source table.

Comment: @JeffReddy Sorry, I mean change it to use the alias of the destination.

Comment: That gets me the error: Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The multi-part identifier "i1.Z_IMAGE" could not be bound.

Comment: @JeffReddy And you're sure the Z_IMAGE column exists on the destination server in that table?

Comment: Yes it exists.  I think it has to do with the linked server.